# Browser issue, script works in Firefox but not with Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have search jquery script, on this jsfiddle **link http://jsfiddle.net/kzpFA/** but it works fine with firefox but not with Internet Explorer. 
What should I do so that this script works same like FF in IE also. Please help

Below snippet I am getting problem for simple click event also

```
$("select option").click(function(){
    var proid = $(this).text().split(":");
    $("#searchInput").val(proid[0]);
});
```

Comment: It doesn't works is not very much information. Do you see error messages?

Comment: what's your jquery version?

Comment: hi wumm, no it doesn't shows any message can you please guide me how to see error if it's there with js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multi-select drop-down list and you bind the options click event: this not correct

for this you can try to bind drop-down `onchange` event to do this(because it's an html element event and it's work on all browsers):

HTML-

```
 <input id="searchInput">    
 <select name="" id="selectbox" multiple="multiple" onchange="getset();">
     <option value="">ankit:naredi</option>
     <option value="">suyog:ma dle</option>
     <option value="">sushil:tade</option>
     <option value="">dipen tiwari: kumar</option>
     <option value="">suyog: sarang</option>
     <option value="">sushil</option>
     <option value="">suyog</option>
     <option value="">sushil</option>
     <option value="">suyog</option>
     <option value="">sushil</option>  
 </select>
```

Javascript -

```
function getset(){
    var proid = $('#selectbox option:selected').text().split(":");
     $("#searchInput").val(proid[0]);    
}
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/kzpFA/11/)

Answer (score 1):

Probably IE cannot bind js events to `option` elements, but you can set `value` attribute to `options` and use the `onchange` event of `select` element:

```
$("select").change(function() {
     var proid = $(this).val().pop().split(":"); 
     ...
});
```

But if user select multiple items using ctrl or shift key (as you set multiple attribute) you're only able to get the lowest or topmost selected value in the list without logic complication

http://jsfiddle.net/kzpFA/12/

Answer (score 1):

Need to update you jQuery code and select html code.

jQuery Updated code:

```
$('#selectbox').on('change', function (e) {
var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
var valueSelected = this.value;
var proid = valueSelected.split(":");
$("#searchInput").val(proid[0]);
});
```

Html Updated code:

```
<select name="" id="selectbox" multiple="multiple">
<option value="ankit:naredi">ankit:naredi</option>
<option value="suyog:ma dle">suyog:ma dle</option>
<option value="sushil:tade">sushil:tade</option>
<option value="">dipen tiwari: kumar</option>
<option value="">suyog: sarang</option>
<option value="">sushil</option>
<option value="">suyog</option>
<option value="">sushil</option>
<option value="">suyog</option>
<option value="">sushil</option>
</select>
```

Need to put option value to work above jQuery.
http://jsfiddle.net/kzpFA/9/